# Tkinter font size not changing

Tags: python, tkinter

```
TFont = ("Verdana", 36) # Changes font
```

Currently, I am trying to change the font size for a GUI in Python. No matter what I change here, the font size in the window stays the same.

Here is how my code looks currently:

```
    TFont = ("Verdana", 36) # Change font

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "GUIIconICO.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Graduate Technical Project")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (TitleScreen, PlayerPage, SessionPage, PlayerPosition):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(TitleScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class TitleScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Home Page", font = "TFont")
        label.pack(side = "top")
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Player", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(PlayerPage))
        button1.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        button6 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Session", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(SessionPage))
        button6.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        button10 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Player Position", command = lambda : controller.show_frame(PlayerPosition))
        button10.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: You need to specify a tuple or a variable that contains one, _not_ the name of a variable that contains one. i.e. use `tk.Label(self, text="Home Page", font=TFont)` instead of `...font="TFont")`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, changed TFont from a string to a variable as recommended

> label = tk.Label(self, text = "Home Page", font = <strike>"TFont"</strike>)
>
> label = tk.Label(self, text = "Home Page", font = **TFont**)

Whilst not listed in this query, TFont was also inside of a parent class causing an error. Placing the TFont variable outside this class seemed to fix this.